# How to 10 to each cell that a name appears?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I add a list of names to a spreadsheet and each time the name appears add the number 10 to one cell.
What formula would I use?

I would put a name like Jones in A1 then Jones in A5. And in D5 (the cell I want the number to appear) it would have the number 20. If I then add Jones in B2 then D5 would say 30. Add 10 each time jones appears.

This would allow me to add up 10 points each time a name appear so I can makes sure the math is right. If the name jones appears 7 times on my workbook then he would have 70 points meaning the number 70 would a appear in D5.

Comment: Please don’t post the same question multiple times.  If you want to clarify a question after you have submitted it, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1324857/edit) it.

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIF() and multiply the return by 10:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:C,"Jones")*10
```

Answer (score 0):

In Cell D5 you may use this Array Formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(A1:C20 = "Jones",1,0))*10}
```

**N.B.**

1. Finish the Formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
2. Adjust the data range as per your need.